# Power function error

Tags: c

Hello I am working on an investment program where you determine if it is better to put as much money as you can towards your student loans before saving for retirement or if it is better to only pay the
minimum payment on your loan and invest the rest.

I'm having a problem with my power function.  it keeps going to infinity enough though I checked each part where non infinite numbers, but futureInvestment = inf each time.  Can someone tell me what im doing wrong here?
Ps I also used include in the header file.

```
totalTime = (retireAge-currentAge);
//A = P(1+r/n)^nt
moneyAfterMinPayment = (userMoney-monthlyLoanPayment)*12;
printf("money after min payment each year is %lf \n",moneyAfterMinPayment);

//test P = 5000. r = 5/100 = 0.05 (decimal). n = 12. t = 10.

futureInvestment = pow(moneyAfterMinPayment*(1+             
investmentReturnRate),totalTime);
```

Comment: you may have forgotten to include "math.h". Can you compile with warnings on? Can you provide a [mcve] ?

Comment: have you checked the arguments to pow? it can help just printing them out to see if they are reasonable

Comment: Posting the types of the variables would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So replace the formula:

```
futureInvestment = pow(moneyAfterMinPayment*(1+investmentReturnRate),totalTime);
```

by this one:

```
futureInvestment = moneyAfterMinPayment * pow((1+investmentReturnRate),totalTime);
```

if the investmentReturnRate = 0.0, the result must be the same as moneyAfterMinPayment.

Answer (score 0):

Typical values:

```
totalTime is about 40.
moneyAfterMinPayment is about 5000.
investmentReturnRate is about 1.05
```

So you calculate `(5000*1.05)**40`, which is `5250**40`, which is about `10**150`.

Now you should discover yourself, what is the correct formula.

Next time you have a similar problem, print values of arguments before and after the expression, and intermediate results.  You will find yourself what is going on.

Comment: In my opinion, the variable moneyAfterMinPayment have not to be in the pow formula, but must be multiply by the pow result.